# Transiently kerberos authentication failure with Kafka client application

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, kerberos, jaas

I am using latest version of kafka and facing issue transiently in connecting my consumer/producer (console) clients to kafka broker over SASL_PLAINTEXT.

This is my jaas configuration file

```
KafkaClient {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useTicketCache=true;
};
```

here are the java properties I am passing:

```
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
-Dsecurity.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
-Dsasl.kerberos.service.name=HTTP
-Dsasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
```

And this is the exception I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:127)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:88)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:710)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:940)
```

Can somebody please help here.

Answer (score 0):

principal and keytab are missing in your jaas file.

see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_kerberos

Comment: I am using TicketCache instead of specifying ketab and principal explictly.

Comment: Does using TicketCache mean you don't have to specify principal and keytab in your jaas file?  Where does it's documentation say you don't have to specify that?

Comment: It fails transiently only. Also when I face issue with connecting to Kafka my other applications using ticket cache work just fine.

Comment: Are you sure your ticket is still valid at the exact time kafka client is failling ? How do you renew your ticket ?

Comment: Yes ticket was valid as I tried to force acquire new ticket and then also it failed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about all those -D properties. Did you follow step 3 and 4 from Asteroid ? You can activate Krb5LoginModule debug : add debug=true in jaas file. Output will be on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest your few options,

1. List all the principles in currently cashed keytab and check if they are correct.
2. If you are trying to do any change to a topic using any principle other than KAFKA, that operation will fail. Set -Dsasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
3. Try setting

   `export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf 
   -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"`
4. If you are using console producer/consumer, you need to provide producer configuration/consumer configuration. Configure the following properties in producer.properties or consumer.properties.

   `security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT (or SASL_SSL)
   sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI (or PLAIN)`

   use command as follow for console consumer

   `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server host:9092 --consumer.config /path/to/consumer.properties --topic Topic`

Hope this would help :)

Comment: Thanks for Help. I didn't grasp #2 completely. Client principal will be of the form '<username>/host@REALM' in general so where is this service name is coming up. If it is for kafka server then yes, I am having principal of the form 'HTTP/host@realm' and have set -Dsasl.kerberos.service.name=HTTP in both kafka server and consumer/producer. Am I missing something?

Comment: sasl.kerberos.service.name should match the name of principle for service kafka. Typically it is set as kafka/host@RELM. And it has full rights to manipulate kafka. If you use any other service name (which does not have full rights to manipulate kafka) then attempting do any change on kafka topics will fail.

Comment: Kafka server are are also running with HTTP/host@REALM. (have set this property to HTTP in both kafka server as well as producer/consumer)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but running brokers with HTTP may cause problems due to reason in my 2nd point. Try changing your principle to kafka (If you have created a principle for kafka)

Comment: You are missing java property -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf

Comment: Forgot to add that but I am actually passing that property. without that it will always happen and not transiently.